# How to find Customers with more than 1 order in a day over a year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a query I am using to find customers who have made 2 or more orders in a single day. I have the following query.

```
    SELECT h.order_number, h.date,
           t.customer_number, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.Address, t.city, t.state,
           c.customer_number, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.address, c.city, c.state     
         FROM Order_Table h
         JOIN Customer c ON h.customer_number = c.customer_number   
         JOIN OrderShipping s ON h.order_number = s.order_number    
         JOIN Customer t ON s.customer_number = t.customer_number 
    WHERE h.date > '2021/01/01' 
    GROUP BY h.date, h.order_number,
             c.customer_number, c.first, c.last, c.address, c.apartment, c.address2, c.city, c.state, c.zip,
             t.customer_number, t.first, t.last, t.Address, t.apartment, t.Address2, t.city, t.state, t.zip 
    HAVING COUNT(c.customer_number) > 1
```

I am having a hard time coming up with how to get 1 customer with multiple c.customer_number orders.

I also want orders where it is being ordered by the c.customer_number but shipping to the t.customer_number. THis is why I added the ordrshipping and second customer table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're grouping on all of those columns, I doubt the `COUNT` expression is every going to return more than `1`.

Comment: Please share table structures with sample data and desired result.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "more than one order in a day over a year".  Is that more than 365 orders?  Is that any single day with two orders?

Comment: Why is shipping relevant to your answer? Why do you need to join to Customer twice? I suggest you don't - start over with a simple query against Order_Table - ignore the need for customer information. Now - seems you need to COUNT (hint) something on a customer / date basis as a start. When that works, then (or maybe not) add the additional criteria of shipping (or is that unrelated to the <more than 1 per day> set of rows?).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count orders for a particular customer number, remove the order_number from group by clause:

```
SELECT h.date, t.customer_number, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.Address, t.city, 
t.state, c.customer_number, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.address, c.city, c.state
FROM Order_Table h
JOIN Customer c ON h.customer_number = c.customer_number
JOIN OrderShipping s ON h.order_number = s.order_number
JOIN Customer t ON s.customer_number = t.customer_number 
WHERE h.date > '2021/01/01' 
GROUP BY h.date, c.customer_number, c.first, c.last, c.address, c.apartment, 
c.address2, c.city, c.state, c.zip, t.customer_number, t.first, t.last, t.Address, 
t.apartment, t.Address2, t.city, t.state, t.zip 
HAVING COUNT(c.order_number) > 1
```

Share more details on the individual table structures and expected output for more specific answer.